# How to format Date to print in Capital letters

Tags: html, css, jsp, jsp-tags

I have the below JSP code, which prints on page like

> USE BY:APR/04/2017

Now I want it to be printed as

> Use By:APR/04/2017

Though the value of label.global.useBy is "Use By" it is getting capitalized because of the style I have defined in CSS. I have done that to render the month in all CAPS. Else it was getting printed as

> Use By : Apr/04/2017

Could you please suggest as to how can I Keep "Use By" as is and juts make month in caps, as:

> Use By: APR/04/2017

```
<td class="contentArea"><bean:message key="label.global.useBy"/>: <bean:write name="details"property="expirationDate" formatKey="format.date.certificate"  /></td>
```

Associated CSS

```
.contentArea {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the generated HTML. You can add class to date or can use decendent selector to make date capital.

Comment: @RahulKapuriya How can I add class to the property "expirationDate" alone? Or how can I use decendent selector for a property inside TD. Could you please suggest.

Comment: Just add the HTML here that browser renders. e.g: <td></span>Use by</span>: <span>Apr/04/2017</span></td>

Comment: I can use span if my data is static. In my case its a variable like:<td class="contentArea"><bean:message key="label.global.useBy"/>: <bean:write name="details"property="expirationDate" formatKey="format.date.certificate"  /></td>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Rahul Kapuriya,
I use SPAN tag inside TD like so,

```
  <td class="contentArea"><bean:message key="label.global.useBy"/>: <span style="font-weight:bold; text-transform: uppercase;"><bean:write name="details"
    property="expirationDate" formatKey="format.date.certificate" /><span></td>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> "You are welcome" *-Rahul Kapuriya*

You can use **`<strong>`** tag so you don't have to add style `font-weight:bold`

Like this:

```
<td class="contentArea"><bean:message key="label.global.useBy"/>: <strong style="text-transform: uppercase;"><bean:write name="details"
property="expirationDate" formatKey="format.date.certificate" /><strong></td>
```